# Number Theory Problem Related to Prime Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose $n$ is a product of $3$ primes $$p_1,p_2,p_3$$
such that,
$$p_1<p_2<p_3$$
Given, $p_1$ is a $2$ digit integer and $n-1$ is a perfect square, we need to compute the minimum possible value of $n$.

**My work:**
Clearly $n$ is odd by parity, so we can conclude $n-1$ must be even, so we can write,
$$n-1=k^2$$
$$n-1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 .$$

So, we can write $n = 3k+2$ for some integer or $n=3k+1$.This is as far as I got, please drop me some hints or suggestion as how to proceed further.

Note: The problem originally asked for the last $2$ digits, which can be obtained by hit and trial, but I want to know how to solve this without it.
Thanks.

Comment: How did you find the last $2$ digits?

Comment: @Servaes By using the fact that the last digit of n can be either a 1 or a 7 and hit and trial afterwards

Comment: Kayotik, actually $n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ is *not* a parity contradiction. Moreover the minimum value of $n$ such that $n$ is equal to the product of three different primes, the lesser of which is a two digit integer and $n-1$ is a perfect square, is $n=30277=13\cdot17\cdot137=174^2+1$. Note that $n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, so actually it is *not* a contradiction.

Comment: @Angelo I understood that can you please tell me how did you get to the answer, also I think you have posted the same comment twice by mistake.

Comment: @Kayotik It is not clear to me what you are checking by trial and error.

Comment: @Kayotik As for the actual answer; this can be done by a simple brute force check. Simply factor numbers of the form $n=m^2+1$ until you find one with the right kind of factorization. It helps to note that $m\equiv0,4,6\pmod{10}$ is necessary.

Comment: @Kayotik, you cannot rule out the possibility that $n-1\equiv0\pmod 3$ because it is *not* a contradiction, consequently you cannot deduce that $n=3k+2$ for some $k$ integer.

Comment: I'll just add that we have immediately that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo each of the primes.  So each prime is of the shape $4k+1$.

Comment: @Angelo Yes you are correct, I will edit it.

Comment: @B.Goddard Thanks for the amazing observation, even though it demands a very basic hit and trial I found it to be simplest solution considering the general observation of the quadratic residue was the same for all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}\text{Let }\,n=p_1\!\cdot\!p_2\!\cdot\!p_3\,\text{ where }&\;p_1<p_2<p_3\;\text{ are primes and }\\&\,11\leqslant p_1\leqslant97\,.\end{align}$

Let $\,k\in\Bbb N\,$ such that $\,n=k^2+1\,.$

As @Servaes pointed out, $\,k=0,4,6\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_{10}\,,\,$ indeed :
$p_1\,,\,p_2\,,\,p_3=1,3,7,9\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z_{10}\;\;,$
$k^2=n-1=p_1\!\cdot\!p_2\!\cdot\!p_3-1=0,2,6,8\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z_{10}\;\;,\;\;$ hence ,
$k=0,4,6\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_{10}\,.$

Since $\,n=p_1\!\cdot\!p_2\!\cdot\!p_3=k^2+1\,,\,$ it follows that $\,-1\,$ is a square in $\,\Bbb Z_{p_1}\,,\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_{p_2}$ and in $\,\Bbb Z_{p_3}\,,\,$ hence $\,p_1,p_2,p_3=1\;$ in $\,\Bbb Z_4\,.$

Consequently, it results that $\,p_1\geqslant13\,,\,p_2\geqslant17\,,\,p_3\geqslant29\,.$

Now we will consider the case $\,p_1=13\,.$

If $\,p_1=13\,,\,$ then it follows that $\,k^2+1=0\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_{13}\,,\,$ moreover it results that $\;k=5\;\lor\;k=8\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z_{13}\,.$

Since $\,n=p_1\!\cdot\!p_2\!\cdot\!p_3\geqslant 13\!\cdot\!17\!\cdot\!29=6409\,,\,$ then $\,k\geqslant81\,.$

Consequently the possible values of $\,k\,$ are the following ones :

$k=96\,,\,174\,,\,200\,,\,226\,,\,304\,,\ldots\;,$

$k=86\,,\,190\,,\,216\,,\,294\,,\,320\,,\ldots\;,$

and the smallest value of $\,k\,$ such that $\,n\,$ is the product of three different primes, the lesser of which is $\,13\,$ and $\,n-1\,$ is a perfect square, is $\,k=174\,,\,$ hence ,

the minimum value of $\,n\,$ such that $\,n\,$ is equal to the product of three different primes, the lesser of which is $\,13\,$ and $\,n-1\,$ is a perfect square, is :

$n=30277=13⋅17⋅137=174^2+1\,.$

Now we will consider the case $\,p_1>13\,$ and we will prove that $\,p_1=17\,.$

If $\,p_1>17\,,\,$ then $\,p_1\geqslant29\,,\,p_2\geqslant37\,,\,p_3\geqslant41\,$ and $\,n=p_1\!\cdot\!p_2\!\cdot\!p_3\geqslant43993>30277\,.$

So $\,p_1=17\,$ and , since  $\,n=p_1\!\cdot\!p_2\!\cdot\!p_3\geqslant 17\!\cdot\!29\!\cdot\!37=18241\,,\,$ we get that $\,k\geqslant136\,.$ Also $\,k<174\,.$

Moreover $\,k^2+1=0\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_{17}\,$ implies that $\,k=4\,\lor\,k=13\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_{17}\,,$ consequently the possible values of $\,k\,$ are :

$k=140\,,\,166\,,\quad$ but

$n=140^2+1=19601=17\cdot1153\;,$
$n=166^2+1=27557=17\cdot1621\,.$

Hence, the minimum value of $\,n\,$ such that $\,n\,$ is equal to the product of three different primes, the lesser of which is a two digit integer and $\,n-1\,$ is a perfect square, is :

$n=30277=13⋅17⋅137=174^2+1\,.$

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that $p_1$ might be greater than $13$ here?

Comment: @TonyK, read my answer now.

Comment: This could be streamlined a bit by observing that each of the three primes has to be of the shape $4k+1$.  You have the line $n\geq 13\cdot 17 \cdot 19$ which can be replace by $n\geq 13\cdot 17 \cdot 29$.  Also, this observation rules out $11$  with much less work.

Comment: @B.Goddard, could read my answer now ?

Comment: @Kayotik, you are welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the smallest possible integer such that $n=pqr$ for primes $p<q<r$ with $10<p<100$, and such that $n-1$ is a perfect square. Then $n=m^2+1$ for some positive integer $m$. A routine check for $m=1,2,\ldots$ shows that $m=174$ yields the smallest positive integer $n$ such that
$$n-1=174^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad n=13\times17\times137.$$

---

With a bit of elementary algebra you can restrict the search space a bit:

Because $n=pqr$ with $p>10$ we see that $n$ is not divisible by $2$ and $5$, and so from $n=m^2+1$ it follows that $m\equiv0,4,6\pmod{10}$. Because $pqr=n=m^2+1$ we see that $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, $q$ and $r$, so $p,q,r\equiv1\pmod{4}$. In particular $p\geq13$ and $q\geq17$ and $r\geq29$. It follows that $m>80$.

Then a routine check of numbers of the form $n=m^2+1$ with $m>80$ and $m\equiv0,4,6\pmod{10}$ shows that the smallest such positive integer is
$$13\times17\times137=174^2+1.$$